# Variables in application context for command line application

Tags: python, python-2.7, configuration-files, pytest

I'm building a command line application written in Python. I would like to use the ideas of profiles, where each profile has some different values to be used in application.

I manage to do this creating a `properties.ini` file and creating a `config_parser.py` file that contains one funcion which receives the profiles and loads the properties into some variables. Then I import this in every file I need to use them.

I would like to pass the profile as an argument when I execute the application, load the correct properties and put them in the context of the whole application, avoiding `import config_parser` everywhere.

For example, in my `properties.ini` I have:

```
[DEFAULT]
 GLOBAL_EMAIL=example@email.com

[e2e_testing]
 GLOBAL_EMAIL=another_email@email.com
```

In the `config_parser.py` I have:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('properties.ini')

GLOBAL_EMAIL = ''

def load_config(profile):
    global GLOBAL_EMAIL

    GLOBAL_EMAIL = config[profile]['GLOBAL_EMAIL']
```

And for every script I need to use the properties I do:

```
from application import config_parser as CFG

def method(profile):
    CFG.load_config(profile)
    print CFG.GLOBAL_EMAIL
```

Ideally I would like to have this configuration loaded during the execution of `main.py` (which is the entry point of my application) and then shared accross modules inside that package, so I don't need to import the `config_parser` everywhere nor pass the `profile` variable.

I read about `__builtin__` and thought about making the `config_parser` add the variables in the `__builtin__` (so they will be available for all modules in that package), but I'm not sure how to unit test with the Pytest since `__builtin__` will be available only for the modules in the source folder and I will need to mock it somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not parse the config once in main.py and pass the result to all of your modules?

Answer (score 0):

Do you plan to run one profile in one process (or group of processes?). If so, you can use environment variables:

```
# main.py
import os
def load_config():
    os.environ["GLOBAL_EMAIL"] = config[profile]['GLOBAL_EMAIL']

# module.py
def modfunc():
    email = os.environ["GLOBAL_EMAIL"]
```